# using URL's names to create css links

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to take URL domain names and use them to define unique names of css links inside HTML file.
For instance - website: http://www.nytimes.com/ is encoded with 'rawurldecode' (PHP) to css link: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F0.css.

Note - Using encoding is necessary in order to use the links (if I use "www.nytimes.com.css" that should not work..). The problem is that the browser do not recognize them.

when you look at the output, which is inserted in HTML file you will see:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/colors/sitesDownloaded/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F0.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="localhost/colors/sitesDownloaded/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F1.css">
<link href='localhost/colors/sitesDownloaded/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/colors/sitesDownloaded/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/colors/sitesDownloaded/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F4.css" />
</HEAD></HTML>
```

but as I said the links are not recognized by the browser. I guess it is related to the encoding and the use of chars such as "%" and dots.
I have tried "rawurldecode" and "urldecode" (PHP) and both of them don't work..

Another important note:
It is easy to use other unique name but the domain name must be the name of the URL.
Any idea?

Comment: Err. Why should it work? `localhost/colors/sitesDownloaded/http://site.com/` isn't a valid href location and it won't work.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can you strip the `http://`?

Comment: Amal - please note that the link is not called as an "http://" cause of the encoding. it will be string containing the "http".. putvande - no, because I'm saving the css files inside local directory and I need  it to be Independent from the web.

Comment: Why not just echo the host domain into the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link (url) contained char "/" at the end of the string and also "www." and "http://",
all of these were replaced with "str_replace" function:

```
function cutUrlHttpAndWWW($text){
$filtered_words = array(
    'http://',
    'www.',
    '/',
);

$zap = '';

$filtered_text = str_replace($filtered_words, $zap, $text);

return $filtered_text;
}
```

and now it is working!